# How do I call the following method from this IBAction?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, methods, ibaction

How do I call the following method from this IBAction? I want to call the prepareForSegue: method instead of the NSLog(@"clicked");

Here's the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) annotationViewClick:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"clicked");
}
```

Here's the method:

```
// Do some customisation of our new view when a table item has been selected
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure we're referring to the correct segue
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowMoreInfo"]) {

        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        MoreDetailViewController *mdvc = [segue destinationViewController];


        [mdvc setSelectedItemName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placeName.text]];
        [mdvc setSelectedItemAddress:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placeFormattedAddress.text]];

        [mdvc setSelectedItemWeb:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placeWebsite.text]];
        [mdvc setSelectedItemRating:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placeRating.text]];
  //      [mdvc setSelectedItemDistance:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placeDistance.text]];

    }
}
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepareForSegue:` method calls automatically when you performing a segue.

To perform a segue you should use `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, 
for ex. `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showGuide" sender:self];`,

in this case you need assign identifier to a segue in Xcode Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

id try something like

```
UIStoryBoardSegue *segue = ... setup the one you want
[self performSelector:@selector(prepareForSegue:) withObject:seque afterDelay:0];
```

ive never worked with storyboards - but thats how you call a selector :)

Comment: thanks. I just want to run the code that's in the - (void)prepareForSegue: method. Isn't there a way just to call that method without having to set up the UIStoryBoardSegue *segue? the segue is already setup in the (void)prepareForSegue: method

Comment: your 'prepareForSegue:' methods obviously needs to be called with a segue, so i think you need to instanciate it... (not alloc, but get the reference)